# Bootstrap Dropdown is not working in this Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am designing a custom bootstrap wordpress theme. I have used wp-bootstrap-navwalker for nav menu and did exactly how it has been mentioned. but still, "Engineering Services" and "Products" dropdown is not working at all! Please save me!

the site is http://mywp.net84.net/

Comment: _"did exactly how it has been mentioned"_ how do we ensure that yo did exactly the same? Show us your implemented code instead of link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav" role="navigation">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul
          class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#anotherAction">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
      </ul>
```

1. check in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreasPizsa/NzvKC/)
2. make sure include appropriate id in the list.